# Using BreezeJS for internal and external API

Tags: breeze, api-design

I need some advice on how to proceed with this design please:

1. I use BreezeJS internally on top of my Entity Framework Web API. So
   all my data retrievals and saves are done in the Breeze style.
2. I now need to expose an API for external consumption which has a subset of
   the calls I use internally.
3. Ideally I would like to consume the same API internally.
4. I do not want to tell the consumers that they have to
   use BreezeJS on their client-side to consume my API (I am using
   Swagger on top of it)

So, for now I have a separate set of API calls for the External API which go through different validation code and have a structure like:

- Get(item)
- Get(items)
- List item
- Post(item)

etc.

My question is: Am I going down the wrong track? Should I either be using BreezeJS on the ExternalAPI or stop using Breeze internally and consume the External API, OR should I perhaps wrap the ExternalAPI methods around Breeze and restrict the saving of the entity graph to the entity type that is being queried at the time only?

Comment: In #4, did you mean, "I do NOT want to..." ?

Comment: Quite right - updated

Comment: If you don't want the externalAPI using breeze then a breeze controller wouldn't be appropriate because the methods expect a saveResult parameter.  You can have WebApi controllers alongside breeze controllers so I think you're on the right track.